# Setting access control header in Node JS for receiving in Angular frontend

Tags: node.js, angular

I am building a MEAN stack app where I have Node on the back end and Angular on the front-end. I am working on user authentication where I have a login page in my Angular. The login info is set to the Node back end where using bcryptjs I compare the password with the encrypted password stored in the MongoDB database. I then create a token using JSON web tokens that I send by to Angular by setting in the header. I got it working on my computer. But I had to do this.

In my NodeJS express app, in development mode I have my Node server running on port 3000 and my Angular server running on 4200. I had to set:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'x-auth');
```

To allow Angular to access the x-auth header which contains the token using:

```
let token = response.headers.get('x-auth')
```

Without setting the expose header on NodeJS, the header does not show up on the Angular app.
And to set the header in the response, in the NodeJS method that handles authentication, I use the usual:

```
res.setHeader('x-auth', token);
```

So, this is my question:
How will this work when deployed on say Heroku? When the client tried to login, will I need to set ('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'x-auth') so that client can receive the token that NodeJS server sends back? Since, these are two separate domains? Will I need to set this header on production also since I do so only on development now. I tried running the entire app in production mode on my computer and it runs without the need for the header, but I am accessing it from the same domain so there is no CORS issue.

I also tried sending the login POST requests to the NodeJS server through POSTMAN. And I was getting back the x-auth token with or without the expose header. So how does the POSTMAN requests differ from the requests sent by Angular?

Comment: What do you mean by different domains? You can have your nodejs app and angular app in same domain no matter what

Comment: I mean the client tries to login from his computer to the server. So wouldn't these be two different domains?